# Casssaandra CQLSH error - No appropriate python interpreter found

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, environment-variables, cqlsh

I installed cassandra on Solaris m/c and have python 3.4.6. While executing cqlsh command  I get the error

```
bash-3.2$ cqlsh
/work/vaneet/apache-cassandra-3.0.7/bin/cqlsh: line 21:  7194 Aborted   
python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(not (0x020700b0 < sys.hexversion < 0x03000000))' 2> /dev/null
No appropriate python interpreter found.
```

I downloaded python source and compiled the source using make. My env variable are

```
PYTHONPATH="/home/cassandra/python3/Python-3.4.6"
PYTHONHOME="/home/cassandra/python3/Python-3.4.6"
PATH="${CASSANDRA_HOME}/bin:${PYTHONHOME}:${JAVA_HOME}"
```

I am not sure if it is the problem of the env variable or installation or any other.
Please guide through.

Comment: I even tried with versions 2.7 and 2.7.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I Re-installed Cassandra with version 3.9 and python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can now use CQLSH with python 3.x for Cassandra 3.x.  It also includes the missing describe functionality that was removed in Cassandra 4.

https://pypi.org/project/cqlsh-expansion/